# delimit text file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import a text file and have it delimited in the rows which it can be without losing the lines which can't be.
Here's an example:

```
Some text for the title
some more text for a description
some more descriptions.

City,State,Capital
Philadelphia,Pennsylvania,No
Sacramento,California,Yes
New York,New York,No
Austin,Texas,Yes
Miami,Florida,No
```

The portion with commas would be delimited.

I've tried a few things.

This is a token error:

```
pd.read_csv(file.txt, sep=',')
```

This works but sometimes the text files don't all start on the same line so I'd like to keep the information:

```
pd.read_csv(file.txt, skiprow=x)
```

Is there some parameter I could pass to get this working?

```
Some text for the title
some more text for a description
some more descriptions
```

| City | State | Captial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Philadelphia | Pennsylvania | No |

Comment: will there always be the information followed by an empty row before the actual table starts? and what is meant by "can't lose the information of the information rows" what do you want to do with them ?

Comment: @Rabinzel Yeah, there's usually an empty row. Sometimes the information contains a name or ID that I search the dataframe for and then use.

Comment: Don't know if I should add this but I guess any information helps: If I were to throw this straight into excel and then use a comma delimited option, it delimits it perfectly. But I'm sure there's a way to do this in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the text file and read each part seperately, then you could use `pd.read_csv` for it, but as one file, as far as I know, you should just read the file with `readlines()` and some conditions.

Try it with this:

```
with open('your_textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    some_information = []
    row = f.readline()
    while row !='\n':
        some_information.append(row.strip())
        row = f.readline()
        
    data = [x.strip().split(',') for x in f.readlines()]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

print(some_information, data, df, sep='\n\n')

['Some text for the title', 'some more text for a description', 'some more descriptions.']

[['City', 'State', 'Capital'],
 ['Philadelphia', 'Pennsylvania', 'No'], 
 ['Sacramento', 'California', 'Yes'], 
 ['New York', 'New York', 'No'], 
 ['Austin', 'Texas', 'Yes'], 
 ['Miami', 'Florida', 'No']]

           City         State Capital
0  Philadelphia  Pennsylvania      No
1    Sacramento    California     Yes
2      New York      New York      No
3        Austin         Texas     Yes
4         Miami       Florida      No
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right though. The best solution may be to split the file. I can retrieve the variables needed in one dataframe, and look into a way to dynamically skip to the right row number for a second dataframe

Answer (score -1):

I used this and it work correctly based off the text file you provided

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, skiprows=4)
df
```

Comment: sure. IMO this is not an answer to the question. If you read carefully you'll see that the exact same statement already was tested by the OP and found to be working. also the numbers of rows to skip change for different files,  also he said he doesn't want to lose the information in the first few rows. Your statement as itself is right, just no answer here.

Comment: Hi, the downvote wasn't my own, but I'm aware that this option works. However I lose the text that's skipped, which is not what I'd like to do.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up must’ve missed that. Thank you for the explanation